# Resize image and place in a byte array for CrystalReports BlobField

Tags: arrays, vb.net, image, crystal-reports, blob

I've tried to search for this and have code that should work as far as I can see, but the resulting image in my Crystal Report is 5 pages instead of 1 for some reason!

Basically, I have a Crystal Report with a full page image taken from a BlobField that works perfectly when the source image is 2409 pixels wide and 3436 pixels high @ 300 dpi.

When I try to use a source image that is 1700 wide by 2436 high @ 200 dpi, the image height is too great and hangs off the report onto the next page a bit

I thought "no problem, I will just resize the image and the report will display correctly" but I'm having major difficulty in doing so.. Here's the code I'm using at the moment- when using the "normal" image size and this code, everything displays fine in the report but if I need to resize, it stretches massively wide and over FIVE pages which is even worse than leaving it alone! :(

```
Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream = New System.IO.FileStream(FilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read)
Dim Image() As Byte = New Byte(fs.Length - 1) {}
fs.Read(Image, 0, CType(fs.Length, Integer))
fs.Close()

'Byte[] to image
Dim imgMemoryStream = New IO.MemoryStream(Image)
Dim myImage = Drawing.Image.FromStream(imgMemoryStream)

' Check if image is 2409 wide, if it's not then resize to 2409 while preserving aspect ratio. WIN.
If myImage.Width <> 2409 Then
    MsgBox("myimage before: " & myImage.Width & " by " & myImage.Height)
    myImage = ImageResize(myImage, 3436, 2409)
    MsgBox("myimage after: " & myImage.Width & " by " & myImage.Height)
Else
    MsgBox("myimage (already correct for printing): " & myImage.Width & " by " & myImage.Height)
End If

Dim imgMemoryStream2 As IO.MemoryStream = New IO.MemoryStream()
myImage.Save(imgMemoryStream2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
Image = imgMemoryStream2.ToArray

objDataRow(strImageField) = Image
```

So I'm grabbing the original image into a byte array (as I assume the image size is "normal" by default and will just insert it straight into the BlobField) and then converting it back into an image to check the image size. If the size isn't "normal" then I'm resizing the image then converting it back into a byte array to feed to the BlobField in the report.

This is the image resize code:

```
Public Shared Function ImageResize(ByVal image As System.Drawing.Image, _
ByVal height As Int32, ByVal width As Int32) As System.Drawing.Image
Dim bitmap As System.Drawing.Bitmap = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height, image.PixelFormat)
If bitmap.PixelFormat = Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed Or _
bitmap.PixelFormat = Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format4bppIndexed Or _
bitmap.PixelFormat = Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed Or _
bitmap.PixelFormat = Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Undefined Or _
bitmap.PixelFormat = Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare Or _
bitmap.PixelFormat = Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppArgb1555 Or _
bitmap.PixelFormat = Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale Then
Throw New NotSupportedException("Pixel format of the image is not supported.")
End If
Dim graphicsImage As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)
graphicsImage.SmoothingMode = Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
graphicsImage.InterpolationMode = Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
graphicsImage.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height)
graphicsImage.Dispose()
Return bitmap
End Function
```

Maybe I'm addressing the problem incorrectly but basically I'm trying to find a way to allow images of any size to be dropped into the Crystal Reports BlobField and have them take up one full A4 page.

Answer (score 0):

You should have your image (as byte[]) stored somewhere already, pass it to this ResizeBytes function, along with the new dimensions you'd like your returned image to be.

```
private byte[] ResizeBytes(byte[] byteImageIn, int NewWidth, int NewHeight)
{
    //Convert Bytes to Image
    MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(byteImageIn);
    Image img = Image.FromStream(ms1);

    //Convert Image in to new image with new dimensions, padding with a white background
    img = FixedSize(img, NewWidth, NewHeight);

    //Convert image back to a byte array
    MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();
    img.Save(ms2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    byte[] imageBytes = ms2.ToArray();
    return imageBytes;
}
```

The FixedSize function:

```
private Image FixedSize(Image imgPhoto, int Width, int Height)
{
    int sourceWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
    int sourceHeight = imgPhoto.Height;
    int sourceX = 0;
    int sourceY = 0;
    int destX = 0;
    int destY = 0;

    float nPercent = 0;
    float nPercentW = 0;
    float nPercentH = 0;

    nPercentW = ((float)Width / (float)sourceWidth);
    nPercentH = ((float)Height / (float)sourceHeight);
    if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
    {
        nPercent = nPercentH;
        destX = System.Convert.ToInt16((Width -
                      (sourceWidth * nPercent)) / 2);
    }
    else
    {
        nPercent = nPercentW;
        destY = System.Convert.ToInt16((Height -
                      (sourceHeight * nPercent)) / 2);
    }

    int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
    int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

    Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(Width, Height,
                      PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb); //Format24bppRgb
    bmPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution,
                     imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

    Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
    grPhoto.Clear(Color.White);
    grPhoto.InterpolationMode =
            InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

    grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto,
        new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
        new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight),
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    grPhoto.Dispose();
    return bmPhoto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply Dave!
I actually ended up modifying the report object that showed the image instead, but I still majorly appreciate your providing a direct answer to this question :)

I will go back over the code all the same and see how yours does.

Are you able to tell me what's wrong with the code I tried to use? It has msgbox's confirming the resolution I resized to is what I wanted, yet when I put that resized blob into the report it's massive!

Comment: I looked for a long time for a solution to this problem, even delegated the task to my reporting guy and he couldn't figure out a solution using only crystal reports.  So we had to come up with the above to solve the problem and it works great for us.  However, we're using small company logos, etc.  There is a slight drop in quality after the resize, and because of our usage it is not a big deal.  Your milage may vary.